# How to create @OneToOne Lazy fetch and optional = true relationship for composite key entities with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

We have 2 entities `Student` and `StudentDetails`. How to declare @OneToOne relationship between them ?

```
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
@Data
@IdClass(value = Student.StudentId.class)
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARTITIONKEY")
    private Long partitionKey;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENTKEY")
    private Long studentKey;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class StudentId implements Serializable {
        private Long partitionKey;
        private Long studentKey;
    }
}


@Table(name = "STUDENTDETAILS")
public class StudentDetails implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARTITIONKEY")
    private Long partitionKey;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENTKEY")
    private Long studentKey;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class StudentDetailsId implements Serializable {
        private Long partitionKey;
        private Long studentKey;
    }
}
```

1. @OneToOne relationship should be Lazily loaded
2. insertable = false and updatable=false.
3. Primary keys are generated by application
4. Libraries, database used are Spring data JPA, H2 in memory database, MySQL, Hibernate 5

Answer (score 2):

> 1. @OneToOne relationship should be lazily loaded

Only the child side can be LAZY. For the parent-side, you need to enable  [`bytecode enhancement`](https://vladmihalcea.com/maven-gradle-hibernate-enhance-plugin/) and annotate the `@OneToOne(mappedBy="...")` field with [`@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.FALSE)`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-lazytoone-annotation/).

> 2. insertable = false and updatable=false.

This request is only needed if you map the same column on two entity properties. In your case, it's not needed.

> 3. Primary keys are generated by the application

If you need the PK to be generated automatically by the database, you don't need a composite identifier. You can just use a `@MapsId` on the child side to share the automatically generated parent identifier.

Now, you are better off using `@Embeddable` to hold the composite identifier instead of using multiple `@Id` annotations. The `@EmbeddedId` will make it easier to locate an entity. Otherwise, you need to use an entity to store the ids just to fetch the actual entity from the database.

Comment: It worked one way with `@EmbeddableId` ie, I used `@EmbeddableId` in both the classes and create a @OneToOne relationship with @MapsId in `StudentDetails`, then while inserting `StudentDetails` i passed `Student` as a parameter. 

Is it possible to create a `@OneToOne` relationship in `Student` class ? This will simplify our queries because there are more entity relationship between `Student` and other entities.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I went through you blogs and figured out that OneToOne LAZY initialization without a foreign key is impossible unless we use byte code enhancement.

Comment: We ended up creating a OneToMany association instead and changed the getter of this association to always return first object in the collection.